# Windows Drive letter detection

Tags: python-3.x, windows, wmi, partition

I've been tring to create a method in python 3 to detect the windows boot drive letter (Most of the time it is C:) however I am having trouble. Originally I used WMI to search for a partition named Windows but I learned that not every computer comes with the partition with this name (i.e. for HP computers the drive is labeled HP). I haven't been able to come up with something that could distinguish the windows boot drive from other drives. If someone has an idea I am all ears. My code is posted below.

```
def getHDD(): #returns the hard drive disk letter. The hard drive should be 
named "Windows"
     c = wmi.WMI ()
     for physical_disk in c.Win32_DiskDrive ():
          for partition in physical_disk.associators 
("Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"):
               for logical_disk in partition.associators 
("Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"):
                    if ("Windows" == logical_disk.VolumeName):
                         return logical_disk.Caption
```

Comment: Can you not just find the system directory (e.g. `%WINDIR%` in cmd) and compute the partition that it resides under?

Comment: Why not just go through `c.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0].SystemDrive`?

Comment: Is `os.environ['SystemDrive']` not reliable enough for your requirements?

Comment: I am running off winpe so those commands will just return the x: drive that winpe is running on